# Meu programa imprime o mesmo printf duas vezes. C

Tags: c

Olá, eu estou com uma atividade para calcular se um número é primo, se ele não for, calcular seus divisores.
O problema é quando ele é primo, imprime duas vezes o `printf`.

Gostaria de solucionar para saber o que estou fazendo de errado

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int primoteste (int n)
{
    
    int cont,divisor;
    
    for (cont=2;cont<=n/2;cont++)
    {
        if ((n%cont) != 0)
        {
        
            printf(" %d eh primo.\n",n);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
            
    }
    for (cont=2;cont<=n/2;cont++)
    {
        if ((n%cont) == 0)
        {
            printf(" %d eh divisor de %d.\n",cont,n);
        }
            
    }
    return 0;
}


int main ()
{
    
int n;

printf("Digite um valor \"N\".\n");
scanf(" %d", &n);
primoteste(n);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está testando todos os números pra ver se trata-se de um divisor. Quando o numero não é um divisor, você conclui que é um numero primo. Assim, 2,3 e 4 não são divisores de 35, mas 35 não é um numero primo. O que seria melhor, era implementar um contator de divisor. caso no fim, o divisor esteja zerado, então trata-se de um numero primo

```
    ...
int primoteste (int n)
{
    int totalDivisor=0;
    for (cont=2;cont<=n/2;cont++)
    {
       if ((n%cont) == 0)
       { 
           totalDivisor++;
           printf(" %d eh divisor de %d.\n",cont,n);
       }
    }
    
    if (totalDivisor == 0){
       printf(" %d eh primo. --%d \n",n,cont);
    }
}
```

alias, não precisa testar ate a metade do n, pode ser ate 3. ou mais precisamente, até a raiz do n. mas se trocar o **cont<=n/2** por **cont<=n/3**
já será bem mais eficiente, caso teste para números muito grandes

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou bastante!